# Flutter Layout Row / Column - share width, expand height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm still having a bit of trouble with the layouting in Flutter.
Right now I want to have the available space shared between 3 widgets, in a quadrant layout.
The width is evenly shared (this works fine via 2 `Expanded` widgets in a Row), but now I also want the height to adjust automatically so `widget3.height == widget1.height + widget2.height`.
[image: layout]
If the content of `widget3` is larger, I want `widget1` and `widget2` to adjust their height and vice versa.

Is this even possible in Flutter?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Have a look at [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html); wrapping the root Row should provide the effect you're looking for:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Rows & Columns')),
        body: RowsAndColumns(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowsAndColumns extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(children: [
              Container(height: 120.0, color: Colors.yellow),
              Container(height: 100.0, color: Colors.cyan),
            ]),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.amber)),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Adjusting the heights in the containers in the column cause the container on the right to resize to match:

[image: screenshot]

https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/c5b661d7b3b4ca00599e8ef87ff6ac61

Comment: Are you sure there isn'y any other way to do this?
Because in the official documentation, it says not to use this Widget because it is too expensive.

Comment: Note from the flutter docs on IntrinsicHeight: `This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.`

Comment: It's expensive but I don't think flutter provides any other way that is better and faster.

Comment: Is it ok to use it inside a list? @matt-s

Comment: @Sp4Rx tested inside a list and it works perfectly!

Comment: Is it cheaper to call WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback(() {}), measure widget height and set it to the other widget?

Comment: The `Row`'s `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` should be emphasized for this to work.

Comment: How can I put a     ListView inside the container with Amber color? If I place ListView there everything disappears.

Comment: There is a way to avoid `IntrinsicHeight` by using `Table` and `TableCell` with `verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill`. Added the answer below, hope it helps!

Answer (score 11):

Since `IntrinsicHeight` is considered [relatively expensive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html), it's better to avoid it. You can use `Table` with **verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill** in the largest `TableCell`.

Please note that if you use `.fill` in all cells, the `TableRow` will have [zero height](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TableCellVerticalAlignment.html).

```
  Table(children: [
    TableRow(children: [
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Widget 1'),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('Widget 2'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      TableCell(
          verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Text('Widget 3'),
          )),
    ]),
  ]),
```

Answer (score 10):

I think that you can set the height of the row instead, then you only must to set the height of you column containers, and with the **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch** the second row will be expand occupying his parent height:

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            // If you don't have the height you can expanded with flex
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: This solution is neat, I kinda prefer it

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I get `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.` error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to flutter. Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong here. I think It can also be achieved using setState((){}) without using IntrinsicHeight.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h1 = 100;
    double h2 = 200;
    double h3;
    setState(() {
      h3 = h1 + h2;
    });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: h1,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        height: h2,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    height: h3,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U91q.png)

Code can also be found here: https://gist.github.com/Amrit0786/9d228017c2df6cf277fbbaa4a6b20e83

Comment: If you have a big app, you would wanna limit the `StatefulWidget` as much as possible. Alternatively, use `StatelessWidget` with built-in solution. Using Stateful for layout is not technically wrong, but you should not use it unless you have no other option.

Comment: am trying to understand why u use setstate in build ??!! wow....!

Answer (score -1):

if you have used the expanded inside Row and facing for full height issue then just wrap the expanded child with Align widget.