# Flutter - Space Evenly in Column does not work as expected

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45CEw.png)
I am trying to put elements in the red box by having even spaces between each other. (Like giving weight 1 to each of them). To do so, I put "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly" in parent Column but it is not working.

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails
                        .posterPath}",
                    height: 120.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, //NOT WORKING!
                          children: <Widget>[
                            generateRow(
                                Strings.released, movieDetails.releaseDate),
                            generateRow(Strings.runtime,
                                movieDetails.runtime.toString()),
                            generateRow(Strings.budget,
                                movieDetails.budget.toString())
                          ],
                        )))
              ],
            )),
```

This is the code for movie image and the red box. I have created a Row which has 2 elements. First one is that image, second one is for red box.

```
Row generateRow(String key, String value) {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[Text(key), Text(value)],
); }
```

My generateRow method

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @diegoveloper This is what I need: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wQwijv3mP4vyafSGLEdoK10ZxukTAVH1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: put the generateRow method

Comment: would be better if you put all your stateful class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have given the height to the `image` is `120.0`, can you do the same for the other `Container` child. By giving this, I was able to **achieve** what you want.

**Code snippet:**

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl:
                    "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails
                    .posterPath}",
                height: 120.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fill),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    height: 120.0 //added to fix
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, //NOT WORKING!
                      children: <Widget>[
                        generateRow(
                            Strings.released, movieDetails.releaseDate),
                        generateRow(Strings.runtime,
                            movieDetails.runtime.toString()),
                        generateRow(Strings.budget,
                            movieDetails.budget.toString())
                      ],
                    )))
          ],
        )),
```

**Tips to debug:**

- I used `Flutter Inspector` to find the problem. [Refer](https://flutter.io/inspector/)
- Refer the image below. Even though we gave `Expanded`, it occupied just half the size of image. Here the size of `Expanded` is determined by child's size (which is almost half the image size).[image]

Comment: Cool, it works, but why added a fixed height can fix this issue? Can we add a fixed height to the row which can apply to its children? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails
                        .posterPath}",
                    height: 120.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, //NOT WORKING!
                          children: <Widget>[
                              new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Released : "),
                                  new Text("25-07-2018 "), 
                                ],
                              ),
                               new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Released : "),
                                  new Text("25-07-2018 "), 
                                ],
                              ),
                               new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Released : "),
                                  new Text("25-07-2018 "), 
                                ],
                              ),
                          ],
                        )))
              ],
            )),
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the result:

```dart
Expanded(
     child: Center(
     child: // your widget here,
    ),
)
```

This one should be the child of the `Column`, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post:
[Flutter Layout Row / Column - share width, expand height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326170/flutter-layout-row-column-share-width-expand-height)

Essentially, the image element in the `Row` makes the row expand in cross axis, but row's actual constraints are not modified. This is why `Column`'s `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` is not working. It needs a parent constraint. And this is achieved with help of `IntrinsicHeight`. Wrapping `Row` widget with it will set row's constraints to the largest child's size (which is the image).