# Dynamic widget height for Stack child widget

Tags: dart, flutter

Stack has 3 child properties, first child (red background) is partially visible because last child (black background) is on top. I need the last child to be directly below the other two and it should not overlap as it is doing now.  Last child contains dynamic text - more than one line of text causes the text block to shift up instead of down - trying adding a few lines to the last child.

```
return new Scaffold(
            body: NestedScrollView(
              controller:_scrollController ,
              headerSliverBuilder:
                  (BuildContext contrxt, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                    print('scrolled $innerBoxIsScrolled');
                return <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    expandedHeight: 195.0,
                    pinned: true,
                    floating: true,
                    forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
                         Positioned(
                           right: 0.0,
                           left: 0,
                           bottom: -1,
                           child: Container(
                             color: Colors.redAccent,
                             height: 50.0,
                             child: Text("Container 1 Text", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                           ),
                         ),
                         Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Text("Container 2 Text", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 49.0),
                            color: Colors.black,
                            //height: 20.0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 20.0),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: new Text("Container 3",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[800]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              body: Container(),
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever run the above and it should be clear.

Comment: Code will not compile, you should share _scrollController

Comment: @OzanYurtsever comment out line: controller:_scrollController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I am going to give an answer for the **"expanding upward"** problem. At the `Positioned` widget which holds the **"Container 3 Text"**, you have set the parameters like this;

```
Positioned(
     bottom: 0,
     left: 0,
     right: 0,
     //codes continue.. )
```

The problem here is, when you set the `bottom` property as **"0"**, then it is going to be a fixed position for this widget in the bottom side and when this widget is expanding, it will not change the fixed bottom position and that is why it is going to expand to upward. So, instead of this, use `top` property to position this widget **vertically**. Once you set `top` property, then the top position of this widget will be fixed and you are going to see that it is expanding downward. For example;

```
Positioned(
     top: 130,
     left: 0,
     right: 0,
     //codes continue.. )
```

**Addition:** You must be considering that, even thought your widget is going to expand downward after this, it will never cross the borders of its parent widget. The parent widget `SliverAppBar` has the `expandedHeight` property, and you set is as `"195.0"`. Anything goes beyond of this height scope, will not be displayed. From the documentation about `expandedHeight` property;

> If a [flexibleSpace] widget is specified this height should be big
>   enough to accommodate whatever that widget contains.

Since your `Text` widgets are flexible, you must be setting enough space for the `expandedHeight` property.

Comment: If I increase expandedHeight value it works for large text block. If I change the text to a single line, the flexspace has a lot of empty space.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326170/flutter-layout-row-column-share-width-expand-height