# Flutter column fill space

Tags: flutter

I want to make the following **white box** to fill the vertical space , I set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` , I want to put the title at top and the description at bottom of the white box

I don't want to explicitly set the height to the **white box** , I just want force it to fill space

```dart
Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Title'),
                          Text(
                            'Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text('AH'),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                        radius: 50,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Icon(Icons.email)
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Current result :

[image]

[image]

Expected result

[image]

I am not looking for a solution just works! I am learning flutter And I want to know why `Row` cannot extend height

Comment: Can you share the image of your expected result?

Comment: I added expected result

Comment: Can you try wrapping your `Row` with `Expanded` and check if it works?

Comment: After wrapping `Row` with `Expanded` , **blueGrey** box filled whole screen , I don't want it, but white box has correct view

Comment: Try giving Row the attribute crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

Comment: I set CrossAxisAlignment.stretch for Row , and get error : The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.These invalid constraints were provided to RenderFlex's layout() function by the following function,which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!

The solution is to use `IntrinsicHeight` and set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in your `Row`, in your particular case you don't need to set alignment, I'll explain it later.

Now, what `IntrinsicHeight` is doing here which solves your problem? See, when you provide `IntrinsicHeight` to your `Row`, it forces the children of `Row` to take up maximum vertical space available provided that you have set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` property.

In your case, both the children of `Row` are `Column`, first column is shorter than the second one in height, and after setting `IntrinsicHeight`, your allow both the `Columns` to take take up the maximum available space, here it is the max(column1, column2) = column2. So, 1st column takes up the 2nd column height, in case 1st had been larger, 2nd one would have taken the 1st height, you get the idea.

As I mentioned before, you also need to set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to allow this behaviour to take effect when using `IntrinsicHeight` but just because you're using `Column` as children of your `Row`, you can skip it, since `Column` tries to take up the entire vertical space available unless you set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` which you're not setting in your `Row`'s `Column`.

**Solution:**

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blueGrey,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      IntrinsicHeight( // 1st add this
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // 2nd use this
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Title'),
                    Text(
                      'Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('AH'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  radius: 50,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Icon(Icons.email)
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ,I have two question : 1- IntrinsicHeight is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase, I want to use my widget in infinitive list view , is there any other solution? 2- Why adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to `Row` is not working and has error "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height."

Comment: 1. Yes, it is quite expensive to use, if you want to use that in some infinite sort of layout, you should instead give it a fixed height. 2. I am not seeing that error in the current code. Could you edit your post which throws that error?

Comment: The current code is OKAY, I asked that if we remove `IntrinsicHeight` and just add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` we have error! Why?

Comment: @WebMaster Yes, in that case you'll have to face the error because on one side you're saying you want to restrict the height of the `Column` (parent one) to `MainAxisSize.min` and on the other side you're saying you want to allow full vertical space availability of `Row` by setting `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`, they contradict each other, and the only solution to make them work is by using `IntrinsicHeight` which allows `Row`'s children to expand to the max_height(row_children).

Answer (score 2):

just found out soln by wrapping row with `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight`

here is code :

```
Container(
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Title'),
                      Text(
                        'Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    child: Text('AH'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    radius: 50,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Icon(Icons.email)
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: here is same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326170/flutter-layout-row-column-share-width-expand-height

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
body: Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Title'),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              child: Text('AH'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                              radius: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Icon(Icons.email)
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: It is not I want . You put a `SizedBox(height: 50,)` between two texts, I if you remove it or not `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` has no affect!!

Comment: @WebMaster: SizeBox() is used for adding distance between two widgets, how it will not add any space in between, on my side it is working.

Comment: I run your above mentioned code, if you remove sized box, two texts have no space between, You can see that , your UI is same as my first UI, and if you comment MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, there is no diffrence

Comment: You want space between two text right? then whats wrong in that

Answer (score -1):

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    child: Expanded(
      child: Container(
        // Fill available Space.
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Title'),
            Text('Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // there was no need for the and additional column
    CircleAvatar(
      child: Text('AH'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      radius: 50
    ),
  ]
)
```

Hope So, it will work

Comment: Not works, Error:BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.