# Flutter Left-aligned Column with image & label, in ListTile will not expand vertically and crops image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter chat implementation, where for each chat left-aligned message I would like the ListTile to start with a Column that will contain 2 widgets:

- the user avatar image
- their name below

The issue I am running into is that the Column will not expand, and image gets cropped.  Here is an example.  I have tried 2 variations, where I try to set height/width at 70 and then at 100.  I get the same result in both cases.  When I add a line break between first and last name, last name goes "off-screen".

What is the correct way to implement this kind of layout, such that the ListTile expands only as much as it needs to for the provided content?

[image]

Below is the code I tried to make this work.

Notice this line here:
`bool isNameShown = false;`  . *Use this to toggle the state for the error case.*

This is a working standalone that can be copied into a new .dart file and run. Thank you for taking a look.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(AvatarChatListDemo());

class AvatarChatListDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AvatarChatListDemoState createState() => _AvatarChatListDemoState();
}

class _AvatarChatListDemoState extends State<AvatarChatListDemo> {

  var imagePath = 'assets/images/lion.jpeg';
  List chatHistory = ['Hello there Sam', 'Hi Bob, Good day '];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(appBar: null, body: getChatMessageList()));
  }

  Widget getChatMessageList() {
    bool isNameShown = true; // Use this to toggle the state for the error case.

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: chatHistory.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return getNextChatListTile(index, isNameShown);
      },
    );
  }

  double dim = 100;
  ListTile getNextChatListTile(int chatMessageIndex, bool isNameShown) {
    var chatMessage = chatHistory[chatMessageIndex];

    Image leftSideAvatarImage =
        Image.asset(imagePath, width: dim, height: dim, fit: BoxFit.cover);

    List<Widget> columnWidgets = [
      Expanded(child: leftSideAvatarImage),
    ];

    if (isNameShown) {
      columnWidgets.add(Expanded(
          child: Text('Matt Houston',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 20))));
    }

    Column leftSideAvatarColumn = Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: columnWidgets);

    Container messageContainer = Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text(chatMessage, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)));

    return ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        leading: leftSideAvatarColumn,
        title: messageContainer);
  }
}
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want the ListTile row to expand to fit both the name and image when name is shown? if not try setting `dense:true`, in the your ListTile widget and see if that helps

Comment: Correct, as you state: ListTile row should *" ... expand to fit both the name and image when name is shown"*, and .. image should not be cropped in any case

Comment: did u tried `IntrinsicHeight` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326170/flutter-layout-row-column-share-width-expand-height

Comment: Hi, I did try `IntrinsicHeight`.  Thanks for the suggestion, I like the idea of how it can be used, however, I wasn't sure the best way to configure it. I added an answer here with details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(AvatarChatListDemo());

class AvatarChatListDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AvatarChatListDemoState createState() => _AvatarChatListDemoState();
}

class _AvatarChatListDemoState extends State<AvatarChatListDemo> {
  var imagePath = 'assets/images/lion.jpg';
  List chatHistory = ['Hello there Sam', 'Hi Bob, Good day '];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(appBar: null, body: getChatMessageList()));
  }

  Widget getChatMessageList() {
    bool isNameShown = true; // Use this to toggle the state for the error case.

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: chatHistory.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return getNextChatListTile(index, isNameShown);
      },
    );
  }

  double dim = 100;
  Widget getNextChatListTile(int chatMessageIndex, bool isNameShown) {
    var chatMessage = chatHistory[chatMessageIndex];

    Image leftSideAvatarImage =
        Image.asset(imagePath, width: dim, height: dim, fit: BoxFit.contain);

    List<Widget> columnWidgets = [
      leftSideAvatarImage,
    ];

    if (isNameShown) {
      columnWidgets.add(
        Text(
          'Matt Houston',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
        ),
      );
    }

    var leftSideAvatarColumn = ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: columnWidgets),
    );

    Container messageContainer = Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text(chatMessage, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)));

    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[leftSideAvatarColumn, messageContainer],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that fixed it, Thank you.  I see the main diffs from my original attempt are: 1) use of `fit: BoxFit.contain`, 2) `ConstrainedBox` wraps the `BoxConstraints`, and 3) instead of `ListTile` we return just a `Row` inside `Padding`

Comment: There are several types of widgets,
Pre-styled widgets usually cupertino or material widgets. `ListTile`, `AppBar`, buttons, sliders, ...etc. Sometimes they have customization options, but usually they are very strict. In the `html` world it would be `html` frameworks like `bootstrap`.
Basis layout widgets: `Container`, `Text`, `ListView`, `Row`, `Column`. These widgets are much more flexible. In `html` it’s `html tags` with `css`.

Comment: Functional widgets: different state management widget + animation + different widgets to work events (like touch or scroll), these widgets exist to add extra functionality in the `html` word it’s `js`.

So.. usually if you can't do something with pre-styled widgets, the easiest way to solve it is to create your own widget by combination of the basis layout widgets.

Comment: Your point about the Pre-Styled widgets and the analogy with HTML tags, that is very helpful.  I was under the impression I "must"/strongly-should use a ListTile with the ListView.  I have to remember that a Widget in Flutter is a Widget, and I can use widgets interchangeably.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the update with `IntrinsicHeight`.  I'm not sure if I applied it correctly or where it can be optimized.  The issue is that it distributes the space more evenly, and doesn't minimize the surrounding empty space enough:

```
return ListTile(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    // leading: leftSideAvatarColumn,
    // title: messageContainer);
    title: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
        Expanded(
          child: leftSideAvatarColumn,
        ),
        Expanded(child: messageContainer),
      ]),
    ));
```

[image]

Although I do like it because I have to move less code around, [@Kherel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62250599/2162226) is a more accurate solution because it manages both the vertical and horizontal space better.. all of that empty space is compressed and left-aligned.

For future reference - if there's a way to optimize this to do the same I think it would be interesting for anyone working on this type of scenario.  If someone else needs it, I suppose they can make a new post.