# How to make child to fit height in a Row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, row, height

I have a `Row` widget with the Input files and search button. And the Row is inside A Column.

[image]

How do I make a search button to fit the height of the row, Making the button size equal to the Input field height?

I Tried adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` to the Row but getting the error:-

`BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.`

I don't have the height of the input field. And not want to hardcode the height of the button as it should always match the height of the Input box.

Also, Assigning the height to the Row and adding `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` does not change the height of the Input Field, the only button is changing.

What is the issue here and how to fix this?

```
Row(
  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'search',
            hintStyle:
                Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 8, horizontal: 20
            ),
            fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            filled: true,
          ),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.search,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can wrap the row in an `IntrinsicHeight` with the `Row` having a `crossAxisAlignment` of `CrossAxisAlignment.strech`. For example:

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [TextField(..), TextButton(..)],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same requirement - I wanted to have square `Container` on the end of the `TextField`. But since text size and therefore text input height might change over time, I didn't wanted to hardcode its size.

One solution is to simply use [`suffixIcon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html) on `TextField` as part of the text input (*red* square).

In my case, I had to use extra `Widget` outside of the `TextField`.
The key here is to use:

1. `IntrinsicHeight` as `Row` parent
2. `AspectRatio` 1 as parent of the `Container` (*grey* square).

See code:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search...",
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        // handle on tap here
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.clear,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96cqm.png).

Note, I found the inspiration for this solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330109/1290954).

Comment: This should be accepted answer as you can't always set a constant heigth

Answer (score 0):

I could give you an idea. 
Wrap the `FlatButton` too, within `Container`, and define width and height for those. Something like this,

```
    Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              height: 50.0,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'search',
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      ),
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
                  filled: true,
                ),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                ),
             ),
           ),
       ],
    )
```

[image] 
Or else, at least define `height` and `width` for `FlatButton` and leave the `TextField` to be `Expanded`.

Hope that works!

Comment: It is not working, with this hight of the button didn't change but width is not half of the total width.

Comment: Sort of, height 50 is almost perfect guess for the input size, but if you specify height other than 50, say 100, we have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

To have the `Button` always have the same `height` as the `TextField` it would be ideal to wrap the `Row` widget with a `container` with a fixed `height` and the `Button` with a `Container` with and *double.infinity* `height`:

```
Container(
  height: 48,
  child: Row(
    // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: 'search',
              hintStyle:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 8, horizontal: 20
              ),
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              filled: true,
            ),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: What height would you give to the Row(), here again, you have to guess the height of Input Box.